# Error return by R predict function or underlying Rcpp

Tags: r

I apparently have successively used a newer R package called [`milr`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=milr), multiple instance logistic regression. Admittedly, I do not make any claims regarding the goodness of the model. However, when I try to use the model to predict I get the error

```
Error in logit(cbind(1, newdata), .) : not compatible with requested type
```

when I call predict as follows:

```
miltp <- predict(milt, SQFM.te, SQFM.teb, type="bag") and 
miltp <- predict(milt, SQFM.te, SQFM.teb)
```

However I get a NULL return when I call it as:

```
miltp <- predict(milt, SQFM.te, SQFM.teb, type="response") and
miltp <- predict(milt, SQFM.te, SQFM.teb, type="class")
```

I have tried using factors, integers and numerics, I am perplexed. My online search only yielded

[Rcpp: Error: not compatible with requested type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181068/rcpp-error-not-compatible-with-requested-type)

which is not helpful for me as R and C++ is over my head. All comments are appreciated, some input info is given below I have tried some conversions

```
str(SQFM.te)
'data.frame':   100369 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ arstmade: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ perstop : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ trhsloc : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ acrept  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ radio   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

str(SQFM.teb)
 int [1:100369] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...

print(milt)
Coefficients:
intercept   arstmade    perstop    trhsloc     acrept      radio  
 -1.69306   -0.09544   -7.95369   -0.53375    0.16506   -0.61778  

Residual Deviance:    Inf 
              BIC:    Inf
```

Comment: This is not an Rcpp question. More of an `milr` package use case question that lacks a reproducible example. Perhaps e-mail the developers of the package?

Comment: Thank you coatless, I was unsure about the Rcpp and I am new to this forum. As for a reproducible example, I can try to do that on Monday with a reduced data set that can be posted if it is deemed useful by others willing to look at it.

Comment: Sigh, reproducing the error with data at the scale necessary for posting has proven more time consuming than I thought. I will now take coatless's initial suggestion. Thanks

Comment: I e-mailed the developer of the package and he noticed that "the data type of "SQFM.te" is "data.frame".  Unfortunately, the "predict" function in this current version does not support "data.frame".  Please try using as.matrix(SQFM.te).  It should be okay to run." I did so and the predict executed. Thanks.